# Let $f$ be entire. Prove $|f(z)|\le e^{C|z|}$ if and only if $|f(0)|\le 1 $ and $\exists M>0$ such that $|f^{(k)}(0)|\le k!(\frac{M}{k})^k$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove that given an entire function $f$, the following are equivalent:

1. $\exists C>0$ such that $|f(z)|\le e^{C|z|}$
2. $|f(0)|\le 1$ and $ \exists M>0$ such that $|f^{(k)}(0)|\le k!(\frac{M}{k})^k$

I have been able to prove that 1. implies 2 by using Cauchy inequalities:

$|f^{(k)}(0)|\le k!\frac{sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|}{r^k}\le k!\frac{e^{Cr}}{r^k}$ and then by taking $r=k$ and $M=e^{C}$ we have proven 2.

However, I am stuck at the other implication.

Since $f$ is entire, we can write $f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0}z^k\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$.

Thus, $|f(z)|\le \sum_{k\ge 0}|z|^k\frac{|f^{(k)}(0)|}{k!}$

Then by using the hypothesis of 2., $|f(z)|\le1+\sum_{k\ge 1}|z|^k(\frac{M}{k})^k$.

**Edit:**
Considering that $k^k\ge k!$, we finally obtain $|f(z)|\le e^{|z|M}$, so by taking $C=M$ it is done.

Comment: You can use the fact that $\frac{1}{k^k} \le \frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: You are right, I can't believe I did not think of this. Thank you, I will edit it now.

Comment: Condition $1$ is often referred to as being of "Exponential Type" (it is actually a bit stronger here - order $1$ and regular type)